Extended sphere on Clifford torus
Let define extended sphere as the set of points that have at least one geodetic path to the center $O$ of the length $R$.
Is it true that at big enough $R$, the extended sphere becomes everywhere dense on the Clifford torus?

Hmm, not sure off hand (seems plausible, but I'm not knowledgeable). What motivated this question?
